# Complex parser in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, language-design

Last time [I asked for a review of my tokenizer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172832/complex-tokenizer-in-c), and I would like to thank for all of the feedback! This time I wrote a parser for my language. The parser generates an AST (abstract syntax tree), from which (later) I will generate code in an intermediate language. Each node will have a `Generate()` method outputting the code.
[image: Compilation scheme]

### About the language

The language is called Pearfect and the source files extension is *.pear. Below you can see a sample code of the language. Plese note these things:

- Members whose names are in capital are public, others are private (the same as protected in C#)
- Classes cannot be nested
- Every return statement must be followed by an expression
- There is no `Main()` method, execution starts at the top
- Enums can have any value assigned

---

```
class Animal:
  var greeting = null
  var name = null

  func Greet():
    print(greeting)

class Dog extends Animal:
  var greeting = "Woof!"

  func Dog(_name):
    name = _name

class Cat extends Animal:
  var greeting = "Meow!"

  func Cat(_name):
    name = _name

for (i, i < 5, i++):
  print(i)

for x...10:
  print(x)

dictionary = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}

list = [4, 5, 6]

for item in list:
  print(item)

if 2==2:
  print("TRUE")

func Add(x, y):
  #When a return statement is present, it must return a value
  return x+y

try:
  Add(3, 5)
catch Exception:
  print("Exception")

thing = 55
match thing:
  case thing < 40, thing > 30:
    print("It is less than 40 and greater than 30")
  case thing == 55:
    print("It equals 55")

enum Planet:
  Mercury = 1
  Venus = 2
  Earth = 3
```

### Errors

The compiler should also inform about the syntax errors in the code. You can see an example here:
[image: Errors]

### Review

I would like to hear what do you think about my idea? How can my code be corrected, both when it comes to style and design? What have I forgotten about? The full code is available in [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/michalpaszkowski/PearfectCompiler). If spaces look unnaturally on GitHub, this is caused by the fact I have switched from Xamarin Studio to Visual Studio.

#### Parser.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using PearfectCompiler.ErrorReporter;
using PearfectCompiler.LexicalAnalysis;
using PearfectCompiler.SyntaxAnalysis.AST;
using System.Linq;

namespace PearfectCompiler.SyntaxAnalysis
{
    public class Parser
    {
        private Tokenizer tokenizer;

        public Parser(string source)
        {
            tokenizer = new Tokenizer(source);
        }

        public Application IsApplication()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            List<Node> statements = new List<Node>();
            List<Node> members = new List<Node>();


            bool commaSeperated = false;

            do
            {
                commaSeperated = false;

                Node member = IsApplicationMember();
                Node statement = null;

                if (member == null)
                {
                    statement = IsStatement();
                }

                if (statement == null && member == null)
                {
                    int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                    int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                    while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber == currentLineNumber)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Get();
                    }

                    while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Position > position)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Get();
                    }

                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "The member is not valid",
                                    currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                if (statement != null)
                {
                    statements.Add(statement);
                }

                if (member != null)
                {
                    members.Add(member);
                }

                if (tokenizer.Peek() != null 
                    && member == null 
                    && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Comma)
                {
                    tokenizer.Get();
                    commaSeperated = true;
                }

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && (tokenizer.Peek().Position == position || commaSeperated));

            return new Application(members.ToArray(), statements.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);
        }

        public Node IsApplicationMember()
        {
            Node member = (Node)IsPackage() ??
                          (Node)IsClass() ??
                          (Node)IsEnumeration() ??
                          (Node)IsFunction() ??
                          (Node)IsVariable() ??
                          (Node)IsConstant();

            if (member is Function function)
            {
                member = new Function(function.Name,
                                      function.Parameters,
                                      function.Body,
                                      true,
                                      function.IsPublic,
                                      function.LineNumber,
                                      function.Position);
            }

            if (member is Variable variable)
            {
                member = new Variable(variable.Name,
                                      variable.Value,
                                      true,
                                      variable.IsPublic,
                                      variable.LineNumber,
                                      variable.Position);
            }

            return member;
        }

        public Package IsPackage()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Package)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token token = tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            if (name == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            List<Node> members = new List<Node>();

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Package cannot be empty", lineNumber, position);
            }

            int memberPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            do
            {
                Node member = IsPackageMember();

                if (member == null)
                {
                    int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                    int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                    while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber == currentLineNumber)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Get();
                    }

                    while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Position > memberPosition)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Get();
                    }

                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid package member", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                members.Add(member);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Position == memberPosition);

            return new Package(name, members.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);
        }

        public Node IsPackageMember()
        {
            Node member = (Node)IsClass() ??
                          (Node)IsEnumeration() ??
                          (Node)IsFunction() ??
                          (Node)IsVariable() ??
                          (Node)IsConstant();

            if (member is Function function)
            {
                member = new Function(function.Name, function.Parameters, function.Body,
                                      true, function.IsPublic, function.LineNumber, function.Position);
            }

            if (member is Variable variable)
            {
                member = new Variable(variable.Name, variable.Value, true, variable.IsPublic, variable.LineNumber, variable.Position);
            }

            return member;
        }

        public Class IsClass()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Class && tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Object))
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token token = tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            bool isStatic = false;

            if (token.Kind == TokenKind.Object)
            {
                isStatic = true;
            }

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            if (name == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (name != null && name.Localization.Length > 1)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Class can only be declared in the current scope", lineNumber, position);
            }

            bool isPublic = false;

            if (name != null && char.IsUpper(((IdentifierName)name.Localization[0]).Name[0]))
            {
                isPublic = true;
            }

            Identifier extends = null;

            if (isStatic == false && tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Extends)
            {
                tokenizer.Get();

                extends = IsIdentifier();

                if (extends == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected base class identifier", lineNumber, position);
                }

            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            List<Node> members = new List<Node>();

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Class cannot be empty", lineNumber, position);
            }

            int memberPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            do
            {
                Node member = IsClassMember();

                if (member == null)
                {
                    int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                    int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                    while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber == currentLineNumber)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Get();
                    }

                    while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Position > memberPosition)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Get();
                    }

                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid class member", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                if (isStatic)
                {
                    if (member is Function function)
                    {
                        member = new Function(function.Name, function.Parameters, function.Body, true,
                                              function.IsPublic, function.LineNumber, function.Position);
                    }

                    if (member is Variable variable)
                    {
                        member = new Variable(variable.Name, variable.Value, true, variable.IsPublic,
                                              variable.LineNumber, variable.Position);
                    }
                }

                members.Add(member);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Position == memberPosition);

            return new Class(name, extends, members.ToArray(), isPublic, isStatic, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public Node IsClassMember()
        {
            Node member = (Node)IsFunction() ?? 
                          (Node)IsVariable() ?? 
                          (Node)IsConstant();
            return member;
        }

        public Enumeration IsEnumeration()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Enum)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token token = tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            if (name == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (name != null && name.Localization.Length > 1)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Enumeration can only be declared in the current scope", lineNumber, position);
            }

            bool isPublic = false;

            if (name != null && char.IsUpper(((IdentifierName)name.Localization[0]).Name[0]))
            {
                isPublic = true;
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            List<Identifier> names = new List<Identifier>();
            List<Expression> values = new List<Expression>();


            do
            {
                int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                tokenizer.Get();

                Identifier valueName = IsIdentifier();

                if (valueName == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected enumeration name", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                if (tokenizer.Peek() != null 
                    && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Assignment)
                {
                    currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                    currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;
                    tokenizer.Get();

                    Expression value = IsExpression();

                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected enumeration value expression", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                    }

                    values.Add(value);

                }
                else
                {
                    values.Add(new Expression(null, currentLineNumber, currentPosition));
                }

                names.Add(valueName);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Comma);

            return new Enumeration(name, names.ToArray(), values.ToArray(), isPublic, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public Constant IsConstant()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Const)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token token = tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            if (name == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (name != null && name.Localization.Length > 1)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Const can only be declared in the current scope",
                                lineNumber, position);
            }

            bool isPublic = false;

            if (name != null && char.IsUpper(((IdentifierName)name.Localization[0]).Name[0]))
            {
                isPublic = true;
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Assignment)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected assignment token", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Node value = IsLiteral();

            if (value == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Constant must have a value", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new Constant(name, value, isPublic, lineNumber, position);
        }

        public Variable IsVariable()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null
                || (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Var
                && tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Svar))
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token token = tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            bool isStatic = false;

            if (token.Kind == TokenKind.Svar)
            {
                isStatic = true;
            }

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            if (name == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (name != null && name.Localization.Length > 1)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Variable can only be declared in the current scope", lineNumber, position);
            }

            bool isPublic = false;

            if (name != null && char.IsUpper(((IdentifierName)name.Localization[0]).Name[0]))
            {
                isPublic = true;
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Assignment)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected assignment token", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Expression value = IsExpression();

            if (value == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Variable must have a value", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new Variable(name, value, isStatic, isPublic, lineNumber, position); 

        }

        public Function IsFunction()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Func && tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Sfunc))
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token token = tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            bool isStatic = false;

            if (token.Kind == TokenKind.Sfunc)
            {
                isStatic = true;
            }

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            if (name == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (name != null && name.Localization.Length > 1)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Function can only be declared in the current scope", lineNumber, position);
            }

            bool isPublic = false;

            if (name != null && char.IsUpper(((IdentifierName)name.Localization[0]).Name[0]))
            {
                isPublic = true;
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.OpenParenthesis)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected parameter list (open-parenthesis)", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            ParameterList parameters = null;

            if (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseParenthesis)
            {
                parameters = IsParameterList();

                if (parameters == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected parameter list", lineNumber, position);
                }
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseParenthesis)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No closing parenthesis", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block (colon)", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Block body = IsBlock();

            if (body == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected function body", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new Function(name, parameters, body, isStatic, isPublic, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public MatchStatement IsMatchStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Match)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            Identifier variable = IsIdentifier();

            if (variable == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected end of statement definition", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Case)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Match statement has no cases", lineNumber, position);
            }

            List<Expression[]> cases = new List<Expression[]>();
            List<Block> bodies = new List<Block>();

            do
            {
                int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                List<Expression> conditions = new List<Expression>();

                do
                {
                    int _currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                    int _currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                    tokenizer.Get();

                    Expression condition = IsExpression();

                    if (condition == null)
                    {
                        Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid case condition", _currentLineNumber, _currentPosition);
                    }

                    conditions.Add(condition);

                } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Comma);

                cases.Add(conditions.ToArray());

                if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No case's block definition", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                tokenizer.Get();

                Block body = IsBlock();

                if (body == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                bodies.Add(body);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Case);

            Block defaultBody = null;

            if (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Default)
            {
                int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                tokenizer.Get();

                if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No case's block definition", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                tokenizer.Get();

                defaultBody = IsBlock();

                if (defaultBody == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

            }

            return new MatchStatement(variable, cases.ToArray(), bodies.ToArray(), defaultBody, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public ReturnStatement IsReturnStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Return)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            Expression value = IsExpression();

            if (value == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected return value expression", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new ReturnStatement(value, lineNumber, position);
        }

        public BreakStatement IsBreakStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Break)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            return new BreakStatement(lineNumber, position);
        }

        public ContinueStatement IsContinueStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Continue)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            return new ContinueStatement(lineNumber, position);
        }

        public DoStatement IsDoStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Do)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            Expression condition = IsExpression();

            if (condition == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected condition", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Block body = IsBlock();

            if (body == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new DoStatement(condition, body, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public WhileStatement IsWhileStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.While)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            Expression condition = IsExpression();

            if (condition == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected condition", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Block body = IsBlock();

            if (body == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new WhileStatement(condition, body, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public ForRangeStatement IsForRangeStatement()
        {
            Token[] tokens = tokenizer.Peek(6);

            if (tokens.Length < 6
               || tokens[0].Kind != TokenKind.For
               || tokens[1].Kind != TokenKind.Identifier
               || tokens[2].Kind != TokenKind.Dot
               || tokens[3].Kind != TokenKind.Dot
               || tokens[4].Kind != TokenKind.Dot
               || tokens[5].Kind != TokenKind.IntegerLiteral)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            Identifier counter = IsIdentifier();

            if (counter == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected counter identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get(3);

            int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            IntegerLiteral upper = IsIntegerLiteral();

            if (upper == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected integer literal", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Block body = IsBlock();

            if (body == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new ForRangeStatement(counter, upper, body, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public ForInStatement IsForInStatement()
        {
            Token[] tokens = tokenizer.Peek(3);

            if (tokens.Length < 3
               || tokens[0].Kind != TokenKind.For
               || tokens[1].Kind != TokenKind.Identifier
               || tokens[2].Kind != TokenKind.In)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            Identifier item = IsIdentifier();

            if (item == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected item identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Identifier collection = IsIdentifier();

            if (collection == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected collection identifier", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Block body = IsBlock();

            if (body == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new ForInStatement(item, collection, body, lineNumber, position);


        }

        public ForStatement IsForStatement()
        {
            Token[] tokens = tokenizer.Peek(2);

            if (tokens.Length < 2
               || tokens[0].Kind != TokenKind.For
               || tokens[1].Kind != TokenKind.OpenParenthesis)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get(2);

            int lineNumber = tokens[0].LineNumber;
            int position = tokens[0].Position;

            Expression counter = IsExpression();

            if (counter == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected counter", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Comma)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No separating comma", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Expression condition = IsExpression();

            if (condition == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected condition", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Comma)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No separating comma", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Expression step = IsExpression();

            if (step == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected step", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseParenthesis)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No closing parenthesis", tokens[1].LineNumber, tokens[1].Position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Block body = IsBlock();

            if (body == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected for-statement body", lineNumber, position);
            }

            return new ForStatement(counter, condition, step, body, lineNumber, position);


        }

        public IfStatement IsIfStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.If)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            List<Expression> conditions = new List<Expression>();
            List<Block> bodies = new List<Block>();
            Block elseBody = null;

            do
            {
                int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                tokenizer.Get();

                Expression condition = IsExpression();

                if (condition == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected condition", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                tokenizer.Get();

                Block body = IsBlock();

                if (body == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                conditions.Add(condition);
                bodies.Add(body);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Elif);

            if (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Else)
            {
                int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                tokenizer.Get();

                if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                tokenizer.Get();

                Block body = IsBlock();

                if (body == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                elseBody = body;
            }

            return new IfStatement(conditions.ToArray(), bodies.ToArray(), elseBody, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public TryStatement IsTryStatement()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Try)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get();

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected condition", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Block tryBody = IsBlock();

            if (tryBody == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected condition", lineNumber, position);
            }

            List<Identifier> types = new List<Identifier>();
            List<Block> bodies = new List<Block>();
            Block defaultCatchBody = null;

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Catch)
            {
                return new TryStatement(tryBody, types.ToArray(), bodies.ToArray(), defaultCatchBody, lineNumber, position);
            }

            do
            {
                int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                tokenizer.Get();

                Identifier type = IsIdentifier();

                if (type == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected exception type", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                tokenizer.Get();

                Block body = IsBlock();

                if (body == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                types.Add(type);
                bodies.Add(body);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Catch && tokenizer.Peek(2)[1].Kind == TokenKind.Identifier);

            if (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Catch)
            {
                int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                tokenizer.Get();

                if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                tokenizer.Get();

                Block body = IsBlock();

                if (body == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected block", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                defaultCatchBody = body;
            }

            return new TryStatement(tryBody, types.ToArray(), bodies.ToArray(), defaultCatchBody, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public Node IsStatement()
        {
            Node statement = (Node)IsInjection() ??
                             (Node)IsMatchStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsTryStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsReturnStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsContinueStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsBreakStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsDoStatement() ?? 
                             (Node)IsWhileStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsForRangeStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsForInStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsForStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsIfStatement() ??
                             (Node)IsExpression() ??
                             (Node)IsFunctionCall();


            return statement;
        }

        public Block IsBlock()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            List<Node> statements = new List<Node>();

            bool commaSeperated = false;

            do
            {
                commaSeperated = false;

                Node statement = IsStatement();

                if (statement == null && statements.Count == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                if (statement == null)
                {
                    int currentLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                    int currentPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

                    while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber == currentLineNumber)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Get();
                    }

                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "The statement is not valid", currentLineNumber, currentPosition);
                }

                statements.Add(statement);

                if (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Comma)
                {
                    tokenizer.Get();
                    commaSeperated = true;
                }

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && (tokenizer.Peek().Position == position || commaSeperated));

            return new Block(statements.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);

        }

        public ListLiteral IsListLiteral()
        {
            Token openBracket = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (openBracket == null || openBracket.Kind != TokenKind.OpenBracket)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = openBracket.LineNumber;
            int position = openBracket.Position;

            if (tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.CloseBracket)
            {
                return new ListLiteral(null, lineNumber, position);
            }

            ExpressionList expressionList = IsExpressionList();

            if (expressionList == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid list literal", openBracket.LineNumber, openBracket.Position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseBracket)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No closing bracket", openBracket.LineNumber, openBracket.Position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            return new ListLiteral(expressionList, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public DictionaryLiteral IsDictionaryLiteral()
        {
            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.OpenBrace)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Token openBraceToken = tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = openBraceToken.LineNumber;
            int position = openBraceToken.Position;

            List<Expression> keys = new List<Expression>();
            List<Expression> values = new List<Expression>();

            Expression key = IsExpression();

            if (key == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid key", lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Missing colon", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Expression value = IsExpression();

            if (value == null)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid value", lineNumber, position);
            }

            keys.Add(key);
            values.Add(value);

            if (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.CloseBrace)
            {
                tokenizer.Get();
                return new DictionaryLiteral(keys.ToArray(), values.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Comma)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected comma separator", lineNumber, position);
            }

            do
            {
                Token commaToken = tokenizer.Get();

                key = IsExpression();

                if (key == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid key", commaToken.LineNumber, commaToken.Position);
                }

                if (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Colon)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Missing colon", commaToken.LineNumber, commaToken.Position);
                }

                tokenizer.Get();

                value = IsExpression();

                if (value == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid value", commaToken.LineNumber, commaToken.Position);
                }

                keys.Add(key);
                values.Add(value);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null
                     && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Comma);

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseBrace)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No closing brace", values[values.Count() - 1].LineNumber,  values[values.Count() - 1].Position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();
            return new DictionaryLiteral(keys.ToArray(), values.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);

        }


        public ChainedFunctionCall IsChainedFunctionCall()
        {

            Token[] tokens = tokenizer.Peek(2);

            if (tokens.Length < 2
               || tokens[0].Kind != TokenKind.Dot
               || tokens[1].Kind != TokenKind.Identifier)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            int lineNumber = name.LineNumber;
            int position = name.Position;
            bool passesArguments = true;

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null 
                || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.OpenParenthesis)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected argument list", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            ExpressionList arguments = IsExpressionList();

            if (arguments == null)
            {
                passesArguments = false;
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseParenthesis)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No closing parenthesis", tokens[1].LineNumber, tokens[1].Position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            bool isChained = false;
            ChainedFunctionCall chainedCall = IsChainedFunctionCall();

            if (chainedCall != null)
            {
                isChained = true;
            }

            return new ChainedFunctionCall(name, passesArguments, arguments, isChained, chainedCall, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public Injection IsInjection()
        {
            Token[] tokens = tokenizer.Peek(3);

            if (tokens.Length < 3 || tokens[0].Kind != TokenKind.OpenBracket || tokens[1].Kind != TokenKind.VMInjection || tokens[2].Kind != TokenKind.CloseBracket)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            tokenizer.Get(3);

            List<byte> codes = new List<byte>();
            List<int> operands1 = new List<int>();
            List<int> operands2 = new List<int>();

            while (tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.IntegerLiteral)
            {
                bool check = byte.TryParse(tokenizer.Get().Lexeme, out byte code);
                if (!check)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "The operation code must be a byte value", lineNumber, position);
                }

                if (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.IntegerLiteral)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected first operand", lineNumber, position); 
                }

                check = int.TryParse(tokenizer.Get().Lexeme, out int operand1);
                if (!check)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "The operand must be a valid 32 bit integer value", lineNumber, position);
                }

                if (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.IntegerLiteral)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected second operand", lineNumber, position);
                }

                check = int.TryParse(tokenizer.Get().Lexeme, out int operand2);
                if (!check)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "The operand must be a valid 32 bit integer value", lineNumber, position);
                }

                codes.Add(code);
                operands1.Add(operand1);
                operands2.Add(operand2);

            }

            tokens = tokenizer.Peek(3);

            if (tokens.Length < 3 || tokens[0].Kind != TokenKind.OpenBracket || tokens[1].Kind != TokenKind.VMInjection || tokens[2].Kind != TokenKind.CloseBracket)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected end of injection statement", lineNumber, position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get(3);

            return new Injection(codes.ToArray(), operands1.ToArray(), operands2.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);

        }


        public FunctionCall IsFunctionCall()
        {

            Token[] tokens = tokenizer.Peek(2);

            if (tokens.Length < 2|| tokens[0].Kind != TokenKind.Identifier || tokens[1].Kind != TokenKind.OpenParenthesis)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Identifier name = IsIdentifier();

            tokenizer.Get();

            int lineNumber = name.LineNumber;
            int position = name.Position;
            bool passesArguments = true;

            ExpressionList arguments = IsExpressionList();

            if (arguments == null)
            {
                passesArguments = false;
            }

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseParenthesis)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No closing parenthesis", tokens[1].LineNumber, tokens[1].Position);
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            bool isChained = false;
            ChainedFunctionCall chainedCall = IsChainedFunctionCall();

            if (chainedCall != null)
            {
                isChained = true;
            }


            return new FunctionCall(name, passesArguments, arguments, isChained, chainedCall, lineNumber, position);

        }

        public ParameterList IsParameterList()
        {
            List<Identifier> identifiers = new List<Identifier>();

            Identifier identifier = IsIdentifier();

            if (identifier == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = identifier.LineNumber;
            int position = identifier.Position;

            identifiers.Add(identifier);

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Comma)
            {
                return new ParameterList(identifiers.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);
            }


            do
            {
                Token commaToken = tokenizer.Get();

                identifier = IsIdentifier();
                if (identifier == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid identifier", commaToken.LineNumber, commaToken.Position);
                }
                identifiers.Add(identifier);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Comma);

            return new ParameterList(identifiers.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);

        }

        public ExpressionList IsExpressionList()
        {
            List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();

            Expression expression = IsExpression();

            if (expression == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = expression.LineNumber;
            int position = expression.Position;

            expressions.Add(expression);

            if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Comma)
            {
                return new ExpressionList(expressions.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);
            }


            do
            {
                Token commaToken = tokenizer.Get();

                expression = IsExpression();
                if (expression == null)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid expression", commaToken.LineNumber, commaToken.Position);
                }
                expressions.Add(expression);

            } while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.Comma);

            return new ExpressionList(expressions.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);

        }

        public Expression IsExpression()
        {

            Stack<Token> stack = new Stack<Token>();
            List<Node> postfix = new List<Node>();

            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = token.LineNumber;
            int position = token.Position;

            while ((token = tokenizer.Peek()) != null 
                  && token.LineNumber == lineNumber 
                  && (Attributes.CheckAttribute<LiteralAttribute>(token.Kind)
                  || Attributes.CheckAttribute<OperatorAttribute>(token.Kind)
                  || Attributes.CheckAttribute<IdentifierAttribute>(token.Kind)
                  || token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenBrace
                  || token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenBracket                  
                  || token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenParenthesis
                  || token.Kind == TokenKind.CloseParenthesis
                  || token.Kind == TokenKind.Null
                  || token.Kind == TokenKind.True
                  || token.Kind == TokenKind.False))
            {

                if (Attributes.CheckAttribute<IdentifierAttribute>(token.Kind)
                   || Attributes.CheckAttribute<LiteralAttribute>(token.Kind)
                   || token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenBrace
                   || token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenBracket
                   || token.Kind == TokenKind.Null
                   || token.Kind == TokenKind.True
                   || token.Kind == TokenKind.False)
                {
                    postfix.Add(IsOperand());
                    continue;
                }

                if (token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenParenthesis)
                {
                    tokenizer.Get();
                    stack.Push(token);
                    continue;
                }

                if (token.Kind == TokenKind.CloseParenthesis)
                {
                    tokenizer.Get();
                    while (stack.Count != 0 && stack.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.OpenParenthesis)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Unget(stack.Pop());
                        postfix.Add(IsOperator());
                    }

                    if (stack.Count == 0)
                    {
                        tokenizer.Unget(token);
                        break;
                    }
                    stack.Pop();
                    continue;
                }

                if (Attributes.CheckAttribute<OperatorAttribute>(token.Kind))
                {
                    tokenizer.Get();
                    //the lowest precedence
                    int stackPeekPrecedence = 100;

                    while (stack.Count != 0)
                    {
                        if (Attributes.CheckAttribute<OperatorAttribute>(stack.Peek().Kind))
                        {
                            stackPeekPrecedence = Attributes.GetPrecedence(stack.Peek().Kind);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //the lowest precedence
                            stackPeekPrecedence = 100;
                        }

                        if (stackPeekPrecedence <= Attributes.GetPrecedence(token.Kind))
                        {
                            tokenizer.Unget(stack.Pop());
                            postfix.Add(IsOperator());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    stack.Push(token);
                }
            }

            while (stack.Count != 0)
            {
                if (stack.Peek().Kind == TokenKind.OpenParenthesis)
                {
                    Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No matching parenthesis", stack.Peek().LineNumber, stack.Peek().Position);
                    stack.Pop();
                }
                else
                {
                    tokenizer.Unget(stack.Pop());
                    postfix.Add(IsOperator());
                }

            }


            Stack<Node> treeStack = new Stack<Node>();

            foreach (Node node in postfix)
            {
                if (node is BinaryOperationNode binaryOperationNode)
                {
                    if (treeStack.Count < 2)
                    {
                        Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Missing operand", node.LineNumber, node.Position);
                        treeStack.Push(binaryOperationNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        binaryOperationNode.Operand1 = treeStack.Pop();
                        binaryOperationNode.Operand2 = treeStack.Pop();

                        treeStack.Push(binaryOperationNode);
                    }
                }
                else if (node is UnaryOperationNode unaryOperationNode)
                {
                    if (treeStack.Count < 1)
                    {
                        Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Missing operand", node.LineNumber, node.Position);
                        treeStack.Push(unaryOperationNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unaryOperationNode.Operand = treeStack.Pop();

                        treeStack.Push(unaryOperationNode);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    treeStack.Push(node);
                }

            }


            if (treeStack.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Node result = treeStack.Pop();

            if (treeStack.Count >= 1)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Missing operator", treeStack.Peek().LineNumber, treeStack.Peek().Position);
            }

            return new Expression(result, lineNumber, position);

        }


        private Node IsOperand()
        {
            return (Node)IsLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsConstantLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsFunctionCall() ??
                   (Node)IsIdentifier();

        }


        private Identifier IsIdentifier()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.Identifier)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int lineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
            int position = tokenizer.Peek().Position;

            List<Node> localization = new List<Node>();

            do
            {
                if (token.Kind == TokenKind.Dot)
                {
                    tokenizer.Get();
                    token = tokenizer.Peek();
                }

                if (token.Kind == TokenKind.Identifier)
                {
                    string[] names = token.Lexeme.Split('.');

                    foreach (string name in names)
                    {
                        localization.Add(new IdentifierName(name, token.LineNumber, token.Position));
                    }
                    tokenizer.Get();
                }

                if (token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenBracket)
                {
                    int openBracketLineNumber = tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber;
                    int openBracketPosition = tokenizer.Peek().Position;
                    tokenizer.Get();

                    ExpressionList indexList = IsExpressionList();

                    if (indexList == null)
                    {
                        Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Expected index", openBracketLineNumber, openBracketPosition);
                    }

                    localization.Add(indexList);

                    if (tokenizer.Peek() == null
                        || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.CloseBracket)
                    {
                        Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "No closing bracket", openBracketLineNumber, openBracketPosition);
                    }

                    tokenizer.Get();

                }

            } while ((token = tokenizer.Peek()) != null &&
                     ((token.Kind == TokenKind.Identifier 
                      && !(localization[localization.Count() - 1] is IdentifierName))
                      || token.Kind == TokenKind.OpenBracket
                      || (tokenizer.Peek(2).Length == 2 && tokenizer.Peek(2)[0].Kind == TokenKind.Dot 
                      && tokenizer.Peek(2)[1].Kind == TokenKind.Identifier)));


            return new Identifier(localization.ToArray(), lineNumber, position);
        }

        private Node IsConstantLiteral()
        {
            return (Node)IsBoolConstant() ?? IsNullConstant();
        }

        private NullConstant IsNullConstant()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.Null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            return new NullConstant(token.LineNumber, token.Position);
        }

        private BoolConstant IsBoolConstant()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.True && token.Kind != TokenKind.False)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            if (token.Kind == TokenKind.True)
            {
                return new BoolConstant(true, token.LineNumber, token.Position);
            }
            else
            {
                return new BoolConstant(false, token.LineNumber, token.Position);
            }

        }

        private Node IsLiteral()
        {
            return (Node)IsCharacterLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsStringLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsIntegerLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsRealLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsDecimalLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsListLiteral() ??
                   (Node)IsDictionaryLiteral();
        }

        private CharacterLiteral IsCharacterLiteral()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.CharacterLiteral)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            string value = token.Lexeme;
            value = value.Remove(0, 1);
            value = value.Remove(value.Length - 1);

            try
            {
                value = Regex.Unescape(value);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid escape sequence", token.LineNumber, token.Position);
                return null;
            }

            char c;

            try
            {
                c = char.Parse(value);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Too many characters in char literal", token.LineNumber, token.Position);
                return null;
            }

            return new CharacterLiteral(c, token.LineNumber, token.Position);

        }

        private StringLiteral IsStringLiteral()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.StringLiteral)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            string value = token.Lexeme;
            value = value.Remove(0, 1);
            value = value.Remove(value.Length - 1);

            try
            {
                value = Regex.Unescape(value);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Invalid escape sequence", token.LineNumber, token.Position);
                return null;
            }

            return new StringLiteral(value, token.LineNumber, token.Position);

        }

        private IntegerLiteral IsIntegerLiteral()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.IntegerLiteral)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            bool isValid = Int64.TryParse(token.Lexeme, out long value);

            if (isValid)
            {
                return new IntegerLiteral(value, token.LineNumber, token.Position);
            }
            else
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Integral constant is too large", token.LineNumber, token.Position);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private DoubleLiteral IsRealLiteral()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.RealLiteral)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            bool isValid = double.TryParse(token.Lexeme, out double value);

            if (isValid)
            {
                return new DoubleLiteral(value, token.LineNumber, token.Position);
            }
            else
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Integral constant is too large", token.LineNumber, token.Position);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private DecimalLiteral IsDecimalLiteral()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null || token.Kind != TokenKind.DecimalLiteral)
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            bool isValid = decimal.TryParse(token.Lexeme, out decimal value);

            if (isValid)
            {
                return new DecimalLiteral(value, token.LineNumber, token.Position);
            }
            else
            {
                Reporter.Report(ErrorType.Error, "Integral constant is too large", token.LineNumber, token.Position);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private Node IsOperator()
        {
            Node operation = (Node)IsBinaryOperator() ?? IsUnaryOperator();

            if (operation == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return operation;
        }

        private BinaryOperationNode IsBinaryOperator()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null
                || !Attributes.CheckAttribute<OperatorAttribute>(token.Kind)
                || Attributes.IsUnary(token.Kind))
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            return new BinaryOperationNode(token.Kind, null, null, token.LineNumber, token.Position);
        }

        private UnaryOperationNode IsUnaryOperator()
        {
            Token token = tokenizer.Peek();

            if (token == null
                || !Attributes.CheckAttribute<OperatorAttribute>(token.Kind)
                || !Attributes.IsUnary(token.Kind))
            {
                return null;
            }

            tokenizer.Get();

            return new UnaryOperationNode(token.Kind, null, token.LineNumber, token.Position);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks a heck of a lot like [tag:python]... What's the purpose of your language? What gap are you aiming to fill? Or is it simply an exercise?

Comment: @Mast Well, it's been a long time since I have implemented my last (bigger) programming language. We had our challenge here and I got into doing it again. It is a lot of fun.

Comment: It's 2000+ lines... quite a lot.

Comment: consider writing a Pearfect parser in Pearfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this was an interesting one! A grammar specification would've been useful to verify the correctness of your code, but oh well. Lots of stuff to say anyway, so let's get on with the pear review (sorry, couldn't resist that one!).

### Overall workflow

Your workflow starts with a linker, which reads a file, scans it for `import` statements (while also verifying indentation) and reads any referenced files as well. The content of all these files is returned as a single string. A source processor then removes comments, and finally the parser (which uses a tokenizer internally) translates that into an AST.

- If `Parser` depends on an error reporter and a linker then pass them in as constructor or method parameters ('dependency injection'). Depending on static things makes dependencies harder to track, code becomes more difficult to test and more easy to use incorrectly.
- Parsing each file separately saves work (only the tokenizer needs to look at each character, not the linker - imports can be gleaned from the resulting AST), enables accurate error location reporting (combining files requires you to track from which file each line came), and prevents syntax errors from 'propagating' into other files.
- Tokenizing comments rather than stripping them beforehand removes yet another character-reading pass, and gives the parser more options: it can ignore them, or use them to generate node meta-data (docstrings).
- Don't let low-level components (such as the linker, error reporter or parser) terminate a program or write to the console ('single responsibility'). Instead, let them throw exceptions or provide information to higher-level code (such as a UI layer), which can then decide what to do with it ('separation of concerns'). Lower coupling makes components easier to reuse.
- There's virtually no documentation. Make things easier for your future self by writing small descriptions of the purpose of each component and an overview of how they are meant to be used. Documenting unintuitive and complex pieces of code is also a good idea.

Let's move on to the parser code itself. It seems to work reasonably well, but it contains several problems such as code repetition, the public API being too large, and various parsing failures (especially identifiers, expressions and function calls look troublesome).

### Code repetition

- Creating a class or struct for line/position information would reduce some clutter.
- `Peek(), null-check, token-kind check, Get()` is a common pattern. Consider writing a utility method for it, for example `TryConsumeToken(expectedTokenKind)` or `TryConsumeToken(expectedTokenKind, out token, out position)`.
- There are several while loops that skip tokens on the same line or indentation. A properly named method would not only reduce repetition, its name could also help explain the purpose. It looks like some kind of error recovery mechanism, but I'm not sure.
- A method for marking function and variable nodes as static would also be useful.
- The same goes for determining whether an identifier is public or not. It's not a lot of code, but a method makes it much easier to guarantee consistent behavior.

### Design

- It seems that only `IsApplication` needs to be public, and perhaps a few other high-level methods such as `IsExpression`.
- The `Is*` naming pattern is often used for methods or properties that return a boolean. `Parse*` seems more appropriate here.
- I understand where the name `Application` comes from, but I think something like `CodeUnit` or `CompilationUnit` is more appropriate.
- Why doesn't the main parse method return errors as part of its result? Perhaps as part of the AST, or by returning a small result class that contains both an AST and a list of errors. This makes error handling more obvious and gives calling code more flexibility.
- Error messages are useful for users, but strings are often difficult and unreliable to work with in code. Consider using error codes (ParseError enum) instead.

### Identifiers

- What you call an `Identifier` is actually 4 different constructs:

  - A simple identifier (`name`), which us useful in many other constructs.
  - A qualified identifier (`name(.name)*`), used for package and class-extend names.
  - A member-access expression (`expression.name`), an expression type that should have its own AST node class.
  - An index operation (`expression[expression]`), which is also an expression type that deserves its own node class.
- Without this distinction, you end up having to add various checks all over the place. Those are easily forgotten, which causes inputs like `a.[0]`, `enum a: b[0] = 0`, `func a(b.c, d[0])`, `for a.b in c` and `class a extends b.:` (or `extends b[0]`) to be valid.
- The tokenizer is partially to blame here: it should not treat dots as part of an identifier, because it does not have sufficient context to determine whether it's part of a qualified identifier or a member-access expression.

### Expressions

- Why is `Expression` a wrapper class? A `BinaryOperationNode` or `FunctionCall` *is* an expression. Letting all expression nodes implement an `IExpression` interface would be more appropriate.
- Expression parsing does not take unmatched *closing* parentheses into account: `a)b` does not result in an error.
- Empty parenthesis pairs should probably not be allowed: `var a = 5()`, `a[0]()` and `a()()` look like function calls, but they're not (only `a()` is a function call, the second parenthesis pair is ignored).
- The operands in binary operation nodes are swapped. This may cause problems later for execution order.
- Is the support for postfix notation (`var a = b c + d -`) intentional or accidental?

### Function calls

- I don't think you need the concept of 'chained' function calls - just allow any expression to produce a function, instead of only identifiers. If your language does not treat functions as first-class citizens, then allowing only identifiers and member-access expressions should be sufficient.

### Other parsing problems

- Sometimes parsing stops prematurely, without reporting any error. This seems to be related to line/indentation handling:

  - `enum a:\n  b = 0\n  c = 0` - this should probably throw an error about a missing comma.
  - class a: var b = 0\n  var c = 0` - I'd expect this to be valid.
  - `enum a:\n  b = 0,\n c = 0` - this causes the *linker* to *terminate* the program... (also, tabs aren't necessarily 4 spaces wide)
- A few other problem cases:

  - `a.(0)`, `a.[0]` - this should not be valid.
  - `var a = '#'` - this should be valid, but breaks because of the pre-processor.

### AST nodes

- Some nodes have too few restrictions: `Application`, `Package` and `Class` can each only contain specific nodes, and you even have interfaces for those, but their properties don't use those interfaces. Similarly, binary and unary operations and constants allow any node as operands or value, not just expressions.
- Other nodes are too restrictive: functions require identifiers, the upper bound of a for-range loop can only be an integer literal and a for-in statement can only iterate an identifier, not any expression.
- Dictionary literals, enumeration definitions, switch/match and if statements all contain multiple arrays of related objects (keys/values, conditions/blocks, and so on). That makes them more difficult to iterate (no foreach) and more error-prone (the arrays could have a different size).
- Reusing `TokenKind` for binary and unary operators is confusing. Create a separate enum for each. Not only does this give stronger guarantees of correctness, it's also more self-documenting.
- Why can enum fields be initialized with any expression, while constants can only be initialized with a literal? Do you plan to enforce restrictions during a later AST analysis stage? As for constants, what about list and dictionary literals? Assuming that those produce mutable objects, what does something being constant actually mean in your language?
- It's safer to let `Application`'s constructor accept `IEnumerable<>`'s, and to call `ToArray` internally, rather than relying on the caller to do so. You may also want to expose its content as `IReadOnlyList<>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<>`, to properly ensure immutability.

### Other notes

- `localization[localization.Count() - 1]`: Linq has a `Last` method.
- `Localization` has a specific meaning (translating software into a specific language). It's a confusing name in this context.
- `if (Peek() != null && Peek().Kind == ...)` can be simplified to `if (Peek()?.Kind == ...)`. This also results in only a single call to `Peek`.
- Since your language has a `var` keyword, it's a bit odd to see almost no use of `var` in the code, not even in cases where the type is written out on both sides.
- C# supports readonly properties nowadays, so `private set` can be left out. This applies to almost all AST node classes.
- Debugging would be much easier if every node class implemented `ToString`, or has a `DebuggerDisplay` attribute. A textual representation can be inspected much faster than navigating through a debugger display. Alternately, you could use Linqpad and its `Dump` method for quick tree visualization (a surprisingly useful tool!).
- Finally, there are a few notes from my tokenizer review that I think are worth repeating here: the importance of documentation, using clear, descriptive and accurate names, and the benefit of automated tests.

Good luck with your language, and merry Christmas and a happy new year!

Comment: Well, thank you! That was the kind of review I was waiting for! Now I have noticed that I haven't changed access identifiers on many functions.

Answer (score 6):

Just scratching the surface...

> ```
> private Tokenizer tokenizer;
>
> public Parser(string source)
> {
>   tokenizer = new Tokenizer(source);
> }
> ```

This could use some dependency injection or you simply pass it the `Tokenizer`. But it would be easier to test if there was some `ITokenizer` interface so that you could mock it and its output.

The same applies to the internal hardcoded `Reporter` it uses.

---

Your image shows that the parser produces an AST but the code says something else. There are a bunch of public methods that I guess someone/something needs to call in a specific order to get the desired output.

What I find a little bit weird is that you always use `tokenizer.Peek`. It looks like it was a stack... but where do you call `Pop` or what does `.Peek(2)` do? It does not look like anything .net-itsch. It's also not clear which of the public methods you need to call to actually start the parser and get the AST.

---

From a parser I expect to be looking like this:

```
public class Parser : IParser
{
    public Parser(ITokenizer tokenizer) { ... }

    public AST Parse(string sourceCode)   { ... }
}
```

where I pass it some source-code and get the AST as a result.

---

A few other things...

> ```
> tokenizer.Peek() == null
> ```

You have quite a lot of these (54 to be exact). It'd be much easier to code if you created some `NullToken` or `EmptyToken` or something so that you don't have to check it for null all around the place and instead of doing

> ```
> if (tokenizer.Peek() == null || tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Package)
> {
>   return null;
> }
> ```

just write:

```
if (tokenizer.Peek().Kind != TokenKind.Package)
{
    return null;
}
```

or even

```
if (tokenizer.IsPackage())
{
    return null;
}
```

You use `.Peek()` 251 times here. Don't you think it's about time to create a few helpers?

And instead of

> ```
> while (tokenizer.Peek() != null && tokenizer.Peek().LineNumber == currentLineNumber)
> ```

simply

```
while (tokenizer.LineNumberEquals(currentLineNumber))
```